# How can I change the orientation of the text in the date cell like i want to move it to the top left corner?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-tsx

I want to move the text to top left corner so that the dates in the calendar do not become disoriented. How can it be done?

```
<div style={wrapperStyle}>
        <Calendar
          fullscreen={false}
          onSelect={(date) => {
            setValue(date);
            handleChange(date);
            console.log("selected");
          }}
          dateCellRender={(dateCount) => {
            return dailyFollowupCount.map((val) => {
              if (moment(dateCount.toString()).format("DD") == val.date) {
                return (
                  <>
                    <Typography
                      sx={{
                        fontSize: "10px",
                        color: "red",
                        backgroundColor: "lightgreen",
                        width: "8px",
                      }}
                    >
                      {val.count}
                    </Typography>
                  </>
                );
              }
            });
          }}
        />
      </div>
```

[This Is the current Output]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGfD9.png)

I tried to use display flex to atleast make them inline but it did not change much. I want to make the text go to left top corner so it looks like a memo or something.

Answer (score 0):

**dateCellRender** is used to render additional information that will be always aligned at the bottom. CSS positioning property to can be used in this case.

```js
<Typography 
    sx={{ 
        fontSize: "15px", 
        color: "red", 
        position: 'absolute', 
        right: -5, 
        top: -25, 
    }}>
    {val.count}
</Typography>
```